# How can one mount configuration files in google cloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, google-cloud-run, configmap

I am trying to implement dynamic configuration for a given container image that is deployed on google cloud run. This would entail providing a json file with the given configuration settings to the container on start. Could someone please advise me on how best to provide configuration to a google cloud run instance during runtime via a json file such as is done with kubernetes and config maps?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For now, you can't mount stuff (volume, config, secret) to Cloud Run. It's not impossible that change in the future.

Today, you need to play with environment variable or container args

- Either provide your configuration through them
- Or, embed your configuration files in the container and use args (or env vars) to select dynamically the right one at container start.